# Error on CLLocation subclassing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, iphone-sdk-3.0, subclass

I'm trying to make a new CLLocation subclass. This is the skeleton:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface JFLocation : CLLocation {

}

@end


#import "JFLocation.h"


@implementation JFLocation

@end
```

When I build the class I'm getting this errors:

```
Undefined symbols:
  ".objc_class_name_CLLocation", referenced from:
      .objc_class_name_JFLocation in JFLocation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

Any Idea?? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `CoreLocation.framework` to the frameworks used by the project.

Right click on "Frameworks" in the Xcode project. Click Add `>` Existing Frameworks...

By default the path should be:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.plarform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework
```