# CLLocation subclassing on OSX

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, inheritance, core-location

I'm working on a more advanced `CLLocationManager` mock than the one provided by Xcode and I ran into a strange issue. I have subclassed both `CLLocationManager` and `CLLocation`:

```
// foobar.h
@interface MyLocation : CLLocation
@end

@interface MyLocationManager : CLLocationManager
@end

// foobar.m
@implementation MyLocation
@end

@implementation MyLocationManager
@end
```

Now if I build the project for iOS everything is fine but when I do the same for OS X, I get this error at linking:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CLLocation", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyLocation in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyLocationManager in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Unlike in this question [Error on CLLocation subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314582/error-on-cllocation-subclassing), I do have the proper frameworks added to the project and, as I said, this setup builds flawlessly for iOS, just not for OSX.

FWIW, I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 with iOS SDK 6.1 and OSX SDK 10.8, building for x86_64 with the default LLVM 4.2.

Any clues why this is happening?

Comment: I tried the same with Xcode5 DP3 and the OSX SDK 10.9, the difference is that it does compile but crashes just after launch with this: `dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CLLocation`. This is getting interesting :P

Answer (score 0):

Linker errors are something to do with the framework. Forgetting to import the framework somewhere or add the Core Location framework to the OS X target. If it works for one but not the other, it sounds like the two targets are set up differently.

Double check. Clean the build. Restart Xcode.

Comment: I created a Cocoa app project from scratch and did nothing but pasted the above code in the appdelegate's .h and .m, PLUS added the CoreLocation framework to the target. Still no luck.

Comment: Presumably with the `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>`

Comment: Yup, forgot to add that to my comment